# Hide command output in Bash if exit code was not zero

Tags: bash

I have a Bash command that produces output on STDOUT and can have an exit code of zero or non-zero.

I would like to hide the output if the exit code was non-zero and show the output if the exit code was zero, respectively.

How can this be achieved without running the command twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Save the output to a variable,
- Check the return code and then
- Print the output if it's zero

  ```
  output="$(command)"

  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
      echo "$output"
  fi
  ```

Comment: Note that this will not preserve the last line break correctly. I think you can fix it if you change the value of `IFS`.

Comment: I am using `printf "$output\n"` instead.

Comment: To preserve trailing newlines, you need to ensure the command substitution ends with something other than a newline, then strip the non-newlines later. To do that *and* preserve the exit status of `command`, try `output=$(command; rv=$?; echo x; exit $rv)`. Then, `echo "${output%x}"`.

Answer (score 3):

The status code is only known when the process terminates. So the only way to do what you are asking, is to run the process having redirected its `stdout` to a temporary file, and then when it terminates, examine its status code. If it is nonzero, just delete the temporary file, if it is zero, just output the contents of the temporary file to `stdout`.

Here's a bash script that automates that:

```
#!/bin/bash

temp_file=$(mktemp)    
"$@" > temp_file
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
    cat "$temp_file"
fi
rm "$temp_file"
```

If you call this script `mute` then you can the command `foo --bar` as follows

```
mute foo --bar
```

Answer (score 2):

You can capture an output from a command and check its exit status, without relying on the fragile `$?`:

```sh
if output="$(command)" ; then
    echo "$output"
fi
```

The pattern of decoupling the command and the test is problematic for a few reasons:

- if your script is running with [`set -e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html), it will exit immediately when the command fails, which may not be what you want. Try it:

  ```sh
  #!/bin/bash

  set -e

  output="$(nonexistent_command)"
  echo "Unreachable code"

  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
      echo "$output"
  fi
  ```
- If you insert anything anything between the command and the test, the comparison will be wrong.

That's the gist. See the relevant [ShellCheck Wiki](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2181) for more.